# Button OnClick not firing when url doesn't contains page name

Tags: asp.net, html, button, onclick

I've downloaded a html5 template and started to develop it by ASP.Net 4.5

I have a simple Button in this project in my sign up page!

When I load the page with complete url (http://mydomain.com/signup/default.aspx) everything is OK! But when I want to load the page with (http://mydomain.com/signup/) the `OnClick` event of my Button doesn't fire!!

It's make me confused! anyone can help me?!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you show us the html of your default.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

This is my default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SalaamSocial.signup._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 app footer-sticky"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8 app footer-sticky"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie lt-ie9 app footer-sticky"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="ie app footer-sticky"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html class="app footer-sticky">
<!-- <![endif]-->
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <!-- 
    **********************************************************
    In development, use the LESS files and the less.js compiler
    instead of the minified CSS loaded by default.
    **********************************************************
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/assets/less/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.sidebar_type.discover.less" />
    -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/components/library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.sidebar_type.discover.min.css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <script src="/assets/components/plugins/ajaxify/script.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1"></script>

    <script>var App = {};</script>

    <script data-id="App.Scripts">
        App.Scripts = {

            /* CORE scripts always load first; */
            core: [
                '/assets/components/library/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/library/modernizr/modernizr.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1'
            ],

            /* PLUGINS_DEPENDENCY always load after CORE but before PLUGINS; */
            plugins_dependency: [
                '/assets/components/library/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/library/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1'
            ],

            /* PLUGINS always load after CORE and PLUGINS_DEPENDENCY, but before the BUNDLE / initialization scripts; */
            plugins: [
                '/assets/components/plugins/nicescroll/jquery.nicescroll.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/plugins/breakpoints/breakpoints.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/plugins/preload/pace/pace.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/plugins/less-js/less.min.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/modules/admin/charts/flot/assets/lib/excanvas.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1',
                '/assets/components/plugins/browser/ie/ie.prototype.polyfill.js?v=v1.9.6&sv=v0.0.1'
            ],

            /* The initialization scripts always load last and are automatically and dynamically loaded when AJAX navigation is enabled; */
            bundle: [
                '/assets/components/core/js/preload.pace.init.js?v=v1.9.6',
                '/assets/components/core/js/core.init.js?v=v1.9.6',
                '/assets/components/core/js/animations.init.js?v=v1.9.6'
            ]

        };
    </script>

    <script>
        $script(App.Scripts.core, 'core');

        $script.ready(['core'], function () {
            $script(App.Scripts.plugins_dependency, 'plugins_dependency');
        });
        $script.ready(['core', 'plugins_dependency'], function () {
            $script(App.Scripts.plugins, 'plugins');
        });
        $script.ready(['core', 'plugins_dependency', 'plugins'], function () {
            $script(App.Scripts.bundle, 'bundle');
        });
    </script>
    <script>if (/*@cc_on!@*/false && document.documentMode === 10) { document.documentElement.className += ' ie ie10'; }</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isvalid;
        var emailValid;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtFirstName").change(function (event) {
                validateRegisterForm($(event.target).attr('id'));
            });
            $("#txtLastName").change(function (event) {
                validateRegisterForm($(event.target).attr('id'));
            });
            $("#txtEmailAddress").change(function (event) {
                validateRegisterForm($(event.target).attr('id'));
            });
            $("#txtPassword").change(function (event) {
                validateRegisterForm($(event.target).attr('id'));
            });
            $("#txtConfirmPassword").change(function (event) {
                validateRegisterForm($(event.target).attr('id'));
            });
        });

        function validateRegForm() {
            validateRegisterForm("btnSignUp");
            var mainbtn = $telerik.findButton("<%= btnSignUp1.ClientID %>");
            if (isvalid) mainbtn.click();
        }

        function ProfileImageUploaded(sender, args) {
            alert(args.get_fileName());
        }

        function validateRegisterForm(senderId) {

            var lblErrText = $("#lblErrText");
            //alert(senderId);
            var txtFirstName = $("#txtFirstName");
            var txtLastName = $("#txtLastName");
            var txtEmailAddress = $("#txtEmailAddress");
            var txtPassword = $("#txtPassword");
            var txtConfirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword");
            isvalid = false;

            var rev = document.getElementById("regularEmailAddress");
            if (txtEmailAddress.val() != "" && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtEmailAddress")) {
                ValidatorValidate(rev);
            }

            if (txtFirstName.val() == "" && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtFirstName")) {
                lblErrText.text("لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید!");
                txtFirstName.focus();
            }
            else if (txtLastName.val() == "" && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtLastName")) {
                lblErrText.text("لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد کنید!");
                txtLastName.focus();
            }
            else if (txtEmailAddress.val() == "" && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtEmailAddress")) {
                    lblErrText.text("لطفا آدرس ایمیل خود را وارد کنید!");
                    txtEmailAddress.focus();
            }
            else if (!rev.isvalid && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtEmailAddress")) {
                lblErrText.text("آدرس ایمیل وارد شده معتبر نمی باشد!");
                txtEmailAddress.focus();
            }
            else if (txtPassword.val() == "" && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtPassword")) {
                lblErrText.text("لطفا رمز عبور خود را وارد کنید!");
                txtPassword.focus();
            }
            else if (txtPassword.val() != txtConfirmPassword.val() && (senderId == "btnSignUp" || senderId == "txtConfirmPassword")) {
                lblErrText.text("تکرار رمز عبور اشتباه وارد شد!");
                txtConfirmPassword.focus();
            }
            else {
                isvalid = true;
            }
            if (isvalid) $("#divErr").slideUp(300);
            else {
                $("#divErr").slideDown(300);
            }
            $("#btnSignUp").blur();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body class="scripts-async loginWrapper">

    <!-- Main Container Fluid -->
    <div class="container-fluid menu-hidden">

        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">
            <div class="layout-app">

                <!-- row-app -->
                <div class="row row-app">

                    <!-- col -->
                    <!-- col-separator.box -->
                    <div class="col-separator col-unscrollable box">
                        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
                            <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                                <AjaxSettings>
                                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="panelMain">
                                        <UpdatedControls>
                                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="panelMain" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                                            </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                                        </UpdatedControls>
                                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                                </AjaxSettings>
                            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                            <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" IsSticky="true"
                                Style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:999999999;">
                            </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
                            <!-- col-table -->
                            <asp:Panel ID="panelMain" runat="server">
                            <div class="col-table">

                                <h4 class="innerAll margin-none border-bottom text-center bg-primary">
                                    <i id="iIcon" runat="server" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </h4>


                                <!-- col-table-row -->
                                <div class="col-table-row">

                                    <!-- col-app -->
                                    <div class="col-app col-unscrollable">

                                        <!-- col-app -->
                                        <div class="col-app">

                                            <div class="login">

                                                <%--<div class="placeholder text-center"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></div>--%>
                                                <div class="innerAll margin-none text-center">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/logo/salam_aleyk_2.png" class="border-none" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="divErr" class="panel panel-default col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" style="display: none;">
                                                    <div class="panel-body right_dir" style="color: #EB6A5A;">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblErrText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="false" DefaultButton="btnSignUp">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtFirstName" class="right_float">نام</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"
                                                                    onchange="validateRegisterForm()"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control right_dir"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtLastName" class="right_float">نام خانوادگی</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control right_dir"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtEmailAddress" class="right_float">آدرس ایمیل</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regularEmailAddress" runat="server"
                                                                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                                                                    ValidationGroup="signUp" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtPassword" class="right_float">رمز عبور</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"
                                                                    TextMode="Password"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtConfirmPassword" class="right_float">تکرار رمز عبور</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server"
                                                                    TextMode="Password"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server"
                                                                CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                                                OnClientClick="validateRegForm();return false;"
                                                                Text="ساخت اکانت" />
                                                            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSignUp1" runat="server"
                                                                style="display:none;"
                                                                ValidationGroup="signUp"
                                                                PostBackUrl="default.aspx"
                                                                 OnClick="btnSignUp_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="radUpload1" runat="server" HideFileInput="true" OnClientFileUploaded="ProfileImageUploaded">
                                                            </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
                                                            <telerik:RadProgressArea ID="progress1" runat="server">
                                                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                                                    <div style="width:100%; padding:20px; background-color:#2b5364; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px; text-align:center; color:#fff;">
                                                                        در حال بارگذاری تصویر
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </ProgressTemplate>
                                                            </telerik:RadProgressArea>

                                                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                                                <img src="../assets/images/people/no_user_pic.png" class="border-none" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btnUploadImage" runat="server"
                                                                CssClass="btn btn-info btn-block"
                                                                OnClick="btnSignUp_Click"
                                                                Text="بارگذاری تصویر" />
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSkipProfileImage" runat="server" Text="فعلا بیخیال!" OnClick="btnSkipProfileImage_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="panel3" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                                    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtFirstName" class="right_float">شماره تماس</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server"
                                                                    onchange="validateRegisterForm()"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control right_dir"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtLastName" class="right_float">شغل</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control right_dir"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <label for="txtEmailAddress" class="right_float">تاریخ تولد</label>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"
                                                                    CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                                                                CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                                                OnClick="btnSignUp_Click"
                                                                Text="تکمیل پروفایل" />
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <!-- // END col-app -->

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- // END col-app.col-unscrollable -->

                                </div>
                                <!-- // END col-table-row -->


                            </div>
                            <!-- // END col-table -->
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- // END col-separator.box -->


                </div>
                <!-- // END row-app -->

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Global -->
    <script data-id="App.Config">
        var basePath = '',
            commonPath = '/assets/',
            rootPath = '/',
            DEV = false,
            componentsPath = '/assets/components/',
            layoutApp = true,
            module = 'admin';

        var primaryColor = '#eb6a5a',
            dangerColor = '#b55151',
            successColor = '#609450',
            infoColor = '#4a8bc2',
            warningColor = '#ab7a4b',
            inverseColor = '#45484d';

        var themerPrimaryColor = primaryColor;
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is my default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using NikWebSiteManager;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace SalaamSocial.signup
{
    public partial class _default : PageClass
    {
        DataLayer.UsersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter UsersTableAdapter = new DataLayer.UsersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
        private string PageAction
        {
            get
            {
                return QueryString.Decode("action");
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
            if (PageAction == "")
            {
                panel1.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (PageAction == "profileImage")
            {
                panel2.Visible = true;
                btnSkipProfileImage.PostBackUrl = "default.aspx?" + Request.QueryString.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = txtEmailAddress.Text.ToLower().Trim();
            if (NikWebStrings.CheckCorrectEmail(email))
            {
                UsersTableAdapter.Insert(email, NikWebStrings.HashMD5(txtPassword.Text), txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, "", true, CurrentDateTime);
                int userId = UsersTableAdapter.GetUserId(email).Value;
                Response.Redirect("?q=" + QueryString.Encode(new string[] { "action", "userId" }, new string[] { "profileImage", userId.ToString() }));
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```